# How do I use both a SELECT query and RETURNING inside the same SQLPLUS INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm working on this project I'm using sqlplus and I'm making this procedure in PL/SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE run_simulation IS 
t_order_no stock_order.order_no%type;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO order VALUES (order_no, id, stock, action, tot_shares, rem_shares)
    SELECT OID, cust_id, stock, action, shares, shares
    FROM stock_order 
    RETURNING order_no INTO t_order_no;
    END; 
    /
    show errors
```

I just get the error: SQL command not ended properly. I can't find any information online about how to properly do this. I tried to have t_order_no as a table. I tried having it RETURNING BULK COLLECT INTO. I tried putting the RETURNING before the select. I don't know what else to try anymore. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because - in PL/SQL - you can't use `RETURNING` with `SELECT`:

```
insert into table (col1, col2, ...)
select val1, val2 ...
from ...
returning val1 into ...
```

It works only for `VALUES`:

```
insert into table (col1, col2, ...)
  values (val1, val2, ...)
  returning val1 into ...
```

---

Here's an example:

This won't work:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test
  2  AS
  3     l_id  NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5     INSERT INTO dept (deptno, dname, loc)
  6        SELECT deptno + 1 AS deptno, dname || 'x', loc
  7          FROM dept
  8         WHERE deptno = 10
  9       RETURNING deptno
 10            INTO l_id;
 11
 12     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('returned ' || l_id);
 13  END;
 14  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE P_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/4      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
9/6      PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
SQL>
```

But this will:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test
  2  AS
  3     l_id  NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5     INSERT INTO dept (deptno, dname, loc)
  6          VALUES (85, 'Sales', 'London')
  7       RETURNING deptno
  8            INTO l_id;
  9
 10     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('returned ' || l_id);
 11  END;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> EXEC p_test;
returned 85

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: would the best way to do it over a large group of data be to use a cursor and go over the data and then insert it one at a time so I can use returning on it?

Comment: Well, it depends. You never said what you want to do with the returned value. If you use it later, then yes - you'll need to *iterate* over those rows somehow. A cursor loop would be one choice.

Comment: I want to go through and call another procedure on each order_no that then goes and processes the orders.

Comment: Then you got your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if RETURNING INTO has any meaning inside this query.
It would have been useful in case you would like to manipulate the data further inside the procedure, which doesn't seem to be happening.

What about simple INSERT INTO SELECT?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE run_simulation IS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO order VALUES (order_no, id, stock, action, tot_shares, rem_shares)
SELECT OID, cust_id, stock, action, shares, shares
FROM stock_order 
END; 
/
```

You might also want to COMMIT; inside the procedure.

Comment: I am planning on manipulating further which is why I need it, I just haven't gotten that far yet. I like to go step by step while coding. Get the first thing to work first haha..

Answer (score 1):

That's because , You cannot use the `RETURNING BULK COLLECT` from an `INSERT`. You can achieve your requirement using `For loop`

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Run_simulation 
IS 
  t_order_no NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
    FOR my_rec IN (SELECT oid, 
                          cust_id, 
                          stock, 
                          action, 
                          tot_shares, 
                          rem_shares 
                   FROM   stock_order) LOOP 
        INSERT INTO orders 
                    (order_no, 
                     id, 
                     stock, 
                     action, 
                     tot_shares, 
                     rem_shares) 
        VALUES     (my_rec.oid, 
                    my_rec.cust_id, 
                    my_rec.stock, 
                    my_rec.action, 
                    my_rec.tot_shares, 
                    my_rec.rem_shares) 
        RETURNING order_no INTO t_order_no; 

        dbms_output.Put_line (t_order_no); 
    END LOOP; 
END; 
/
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=646a176127c9ad1f69bf0a2a888ea220)

Answer (score 0):

You should review your sp structure.
Insead of IS, use AS.

Instead of RETURNING use RETURN

Here is an exemple :

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm